# Firebase CLI Avoid creating random object IDs STDIN

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, command-line-interface, stdin, firebase-console

I am using Firebase CLI and trying to update a database with `firebase:push`. I would like to add an object to an existing database structure however it always creates a random object key that I do not want. Is it possible to omit this object key?

e.g.

I have used the following command in the CLI to add the json object.

`> firebase database:push /users/cpaluk <<< '{"name":"cpaluk","key":"cpaluk","id":"test"}'`

The object gets wrapped in an auto-generated random key `KcqrF7JuJChspnOOo5h`.

[image: Firebase Database result]

Thanks

Comment: I discovered that I must append a `--confirm` flag to force confirmation. It seems to be a bug for `database:set` with STDIN so I'm putting it here incase it helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the Firebase CLI with `firebase database:push` it will always generate a push ID for the new data.

If you want to specify the full path of the data yourself, use `firebase database:set`:

```
firebase database:set /users/cpaluk <<< '{"name":"cpaluk","key":"cpaluk","id":"test"}'
```

See the [list of database commands in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands) for the other commands that the CLI accepts.

Comment: Hey Frank, there is a small typo 'database:set' that needs fixing but after that I will accept this as the answer thanks :) There is an issue with the mac CLI that I wonder if you have faced?

When I write the line that you provided into the Terminal, I get the following error: `Error: Missing required options (confirm) while running in non-interactive mode`

If I replace the STDIN with a file path, it works fine. I searched the error and there are reports on Git of an old bug so I forced --interactive but that didn't make a difference. I wondered if you had used STDIN and resolved this?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, I fixed it. I don't recognize the other problem, but must admit I always use a JSON file to send data to the database: `firebase database:set /users/cpaluk value.json`.